# My IIS connecting to remote web service requiring client certificate

Tags: iis, certificate, client

I have IIS asp.net website which it connects to a remote webservice requires client certificate, I have the client certificate installed on our computer hosting iis, But when connecting from our iis to the remote service we got error as our iis can't find client certificate in currentuser or localmachine store!!! How to solve?

Comment: "iis can't find client certificate in currentuser or localmachine store!!!" Did you put it into Personal of local machine store?

Comment: I put it in both

Comment: Then do you use a custom application pool identity? Certificate private keys require access permissions, which if you Google carefully, should be able to learn.

Comment: I don't understand you, please can you explain

Comment: I googling and found the answer: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/901183/how-to-call-a-web-service-by-using-a-client-certificate-for-authentica